# How can I generate a random serial number for each certificate using openssl x509?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

How can I make it so that a random serial number is generated for each new signed certificate issued from a self signed rsa certificate using the openssl command?

I couldn't find anything regarding openssl x509.

Comment: Do you mean how to make SRL file using KEY, CSR, CRT files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best (cheap and only) way I found was to delete the serial file used for the rootCA `ca.srl`.

That way, when a new certificate is issued, by using the `-CAcreateserial` flag, a new random serial is created and thus leveraging the same random number generation used by openssl.

Comment: There's though a very, very small chance that a serial number is used twice. :-/ In theory you need to track all used serial numbers to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

For OpenSSL 3.0 the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-x509.html#CAserial-filename) states:

> If the -CA option is specified and neither <-CAserial> or
> <-CAcreateserial> is given and the default serial number file does not
> exist, a random number is generated; this is the recommended practice.

So for version 3 you won't even need to provide the `-CAcreateserial` flag to create a new serial number file. You only need to check that the default serial number file does not exist.

Also please note, that there was a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458172/between-openssl-3-and-openssl-1-the-behavior-of-openssl-x509-cacreateserial/75163254#75163254), which caused a random serial number to be generated even with the provided `-CAserial` and `-CAcreateserial` and existing serial number file.