# Between OpenSSL-3 and OpenSSL-1, the behavior of "openssl x509 -CAcreateserial" has changed, how should I fix it?

Tags: openssl

With OpenSSL 1.x, I used to sign certifications and create ".srl" files with the following command

```
openssl x509 -in vcom.csr -days 1024 -CAkey ./rootCA.key -CA ./rootCA.pem -force_pubkey vcom_pub.pem -out vcom_cert.pem -CAcreateserial
```

However, after upgrading to OpenSSL 3.x. the option "-CAcreateserial" failed to create new ".srl" files.

After reviewing the OpenSSL 3.x source code, it seems like the option "-req" generates a random serial number; therefore, the source code related to "-CAcreateserial" is bypassed.

To my understanding, it is very important to record the serial number when signing a certificate, to avoid duplication.

Am I doing something wrong with the command? or have I misunderstood the concept of this ".srl" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've continued to investigate into this problem, and found out, that option "-CAserial" is also ignored.
As a result, the ".srl" file is really not requested in the process of signing a public key from a "CSR" file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug which was [fixed](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/18373) sometime near May, 2022. So, since version 3.0.5 it should work as described in the documentation.